# WebApi Http Error 404 Not Found

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having a problem with WebApi 5.2.3 in which if I had a controller like so:

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/values")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController 
    {
            [Route]
            public IHttpActionResult Get() 
            {
                return Ok("data");
            }
    }
```

Currently if i make a request to api/values I retrieve my response "data" just fine.  I would like to handle the case of routes that are not found, for example "api/values/foo".  Currently making the api/values/foo request returns the typical IIS Http Error 404.0 Not Found page.  I would like to be able to handle this and return a json or xml response based on the negotiated content type.  Has anyone ran into this before and how did you solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Also to note, I created a DelegatingHandler and confirmed that my request is not entering the WebApi stack.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to create your custom controller/action selector (IHttpControllerSelector/IHttpActionSelector), take a look into this article which creates a custom one to handle the 404 error.

http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/handling-http-404-error-in-asp-net-web-api

Hope this helps.